# Spring Data CouchBase Configuration : Database does not exists error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to connect to couch db from spring data in a spring boot environment.
Following are the configurations

```
 @Configuration
```

@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.datamigration.dao"})
    public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

```
@Override
protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {

     return Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1");
}

@Override
protected String getBucketName() {

    return "akhil";
}

@Override
protected String getBucketPassword() {

    return "1234";
}



@Override
protected CouchbaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
    CouchbaseEnvironment env =  DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
                .bootstrapHttpDirectPort(5984)
                .build();

        return env;
}
```

}

and the corresponding repository class is

```
public interface MigrationDAO extends CrudRepository<Name,String> {
```

}

When i am trying to connect i am getting the below error

> Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: NOT_EXISTS: {"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

I have tried making the password/bucket name then "name or password is incorrect" error is coming,which means bucket name and password are correct and the code is trying to connect to Db.
But not sure why "Database does not exist." error is coming.Can anyone please help ?

Comment: db name is "test" in couch db.where to specify the db name in the configuration ?

Comment: I assume your question should be tagged with `couchbase` rather than `couchdb`, these are two different products.

Answer (score 0):

For the database you use, the vendor should have a dedicated driver. You can go to the official website to look at the Api documentation, or you can use other methods to connect, such as yml, or use other configuration files.

Comment: Couchbase does directly, officially support Spring Data Couchbase working with the Spring Project.

Answer (score 0):

One must understand that couchbase and couchdb are different.
In couchdb,we have to provide db name mandatorily,whereas in couchbase there are buckets concept.I need to rewrite the code so as establish connection to couchdb from spring